# Java - Improving performance for building up index table

Tags: java, mysql

I am working on a full text indexing using inverted file method where it extracts all the word in a document, and inserts each word one by one into my table in MYSQL.

So far, my program works perfectly fine but I am stuck in thinking how it could be optimize further to improve the time it takes to insert into db. I am aware inverted file has a disadvantage of slow time for building up the index table.

Here is my code:

```
public class IndexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StopWatch stopwatch = new StopWatch();
        stopwatch.start();



        File folder = new File("D:\\PDF1");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                HashSet<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<>();
                String path = "D:\\PDF1\\" + file.getName();
                try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path))) {

                    if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

                        PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                        String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
                        String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
                        for (String line : lines) {
                            String[] words = line.split(" ");

                            for (String word : words) {
                                uniqueWords.add(word);

                            }

                        }
                        // System.out.println(uniqueWords);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Exception while trying to read pdf document - " + e);
                }
                Object[] words = uniqueWords.toArray();
                String unique = uniqueWords.toString();
                //  System.out.println(words[1].toString());



                for(int i = 1 ; i <= words.length - 1 ; i++ ) {
                    MysqlAccessIndex connection = new MysqlAccessIndex();
                    connection.readDataBase(path, words[i].toString());

                }

                System.out.println("Completed");

            }
        }
       stopwatch.stop();
        long timeTaken = stopwatch.getTime();
        System.out.println(timeTaken);
```

MYSQL connection:

```
public class MysqlAccessIndex {
    public Connection connect = null;
    public Statement statement = null;
    public PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    public ResultSet resultSet = null;



    public MysqlAccessIndex() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://126.32.3.178/fulltext_ltat?"
                        + "user=root&password=root123");
      //  statement = connect.createStatement();
        System.out.print("Connected");
    }


    public void readDataBase(String path,String word) throws Exception {
        try {


            preparedStatement = connect
                    .prepareStatement("insert IGNORE into  fulltext_ltat.test_text values (?, ?) ");

            preparedStatement.setString(1, path);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, word);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            close();
        }

    }
```

Is it possible if I could use some sort of multi threading to say insert three words in three rows at the same time to speed up the insert process or some sort?
I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Why do you have a method called `readDatabase` that *writes* to the database?

Comment: That method connects to the database so I could insert the words extracted from the file to the table.

Answer (score 2):

I think solution to your problem - is to use **bulk** insert.
You could try to do something like this:

```
public void readDataBase(String path, HashSet<String> uniqueWords) throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

    try {

        String compiledQuery = "insert IGNORE into  fulltext_ltat.test_text values (?, ?) ";
        preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(compiledQuery);

        for(String word : uniqueWords) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, path);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, word);
            preparedStatement.addBatch();
        }

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int[] inserted = preparedStatement.executeBatch();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            close();
        }
}
```

Modify your `readDataBase` method to have `HashSet<String> uniqueWords` in params.

After that you should add `preparedStatement.addBatch()` call after each item to insert and execute `preparedStatement.executeBatch()` instead of `preparedStatement.executeUpdate()` in the end.

I hope it would help.

Comment: let me try it first ya

Comment: Well, it supposed to accumulate all you inserts to one batch and execute in once. Although **you should probably limit balk size to some reasonable number** (let say 1000 records at the time), since it might affect performance (you don't want to insert 1million rows at the time for sure)

Comment: Okay on my index side, which part should i alter?
long start and int[] inserted is not used?

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't improve the insert performance at all. In fact, it made it worse than my code performs.